# Name Input from widget displays Sidebar name instead of saved data

Tags: php, images, widgets, uploads, input

I wasn't sure how to title this question,so I apologize.
Let me first state that I have no experience with this type of code but I really need to this feature for my website, so I appreciate all the help anyone can provide!

Anyway, I recently got a solution to a previous issue I had which can be found here//

[Create Image Uploader for Widget](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/127299/create-image-uploader-for-widget)

It worked perfectly, but the new* issue now is that I wanted to add a "Name" input and a way to display default text that would show up on the front end.

I found a tutorial here//

http://wp.tutsplus.com/tutorials/creative-coding/building-custom-wordpress-widgets/

it uses `if ( $name )
            printf( '<p>' . __('Hey their Sailor! My name is %1$s.', 'example') . '</p>', $name );` to display the name.
So I tried to add it into my functions.php.

and came up with this//

```
// register sidebar
if (function_exists('register_sidebar')) {
register_sidebar(
    array(
    'name' => 'Left Sidebar',
    'id' => 'left-sidebar',
    'description' => 'Widget Area',
    'before_widget' => '<div id="one" class="two">',
    'after_widget' => '</div>',
    )
);
}

// register widget
add_action('widgets_init', 'eotw_widget');
function eotw_widget() {
register_widget( 'eotw_w' );
}

// add admin scripts
add_action('admin_enqueue_scripts', 'ctup_wdscript');
function ctup_wdscript() {
wp_enqueue_media();
wp_enqueue_script('ads_script', get_template_directory_uri() . '/js/ads.js', false,    '1.0', true);
}

// widget class
class eotw_w extends WP_Widget {

function eotw_w() {
    $widget_ops = array('classname' => 'eotw-w');
    $this->WP_Widget('eotw-w-widget', 'EOTW', $widget_ops);
}

function widget($args, $instance) {
    extract($args);

    // widget content
    echo $before_widget;


    if ( $name )
        printf( '<p>' . __('Hey there Sailor! My name is %1$s.', 'example') . '</p>', $name );
?>
    <img class="eotw-edit" src="<?php echo esc_url($instance['image_uri']); ?>" />

<?php
    echo $after_widget;

}

function update($new_instance, $old_instance) {
    $instance = $old_instance;
    $instance['name'] = strip_tags( $new_instance['name'] );
    $instance['image_uri'] = strip_tags( $new_instance['image_uri'] );
    return $instance;
}

function form($instance) {
?>

<p>
        <label for="<?php echo $this->get_field_id( 'name' ); ?>"><?php _e('Your Name:', 'example'); ?></label>
        <input id="<?php echo $this->get_field_id( 'name' ); ?>" name="<?php echo $this->get_field_name( 'name' ); ?>" value="<?php echo $instance['name']; ?>" style="width:100%;" />
    </p>
<p>
    <label for="<?php echo $this->get_field_id('image_uri'); ?>">Image</label><br />

    <?php
        if ( $instance['image_uri'] != '' ) :
            echo '<img class="custom_media_image" src="' . $instance['image_uri'] . '" style="margin:0;padding:0;max-width:100px;float:left;display:inline-block" /><br />';
        endif;
    ?>

    <input type="text" class="widefat custom_media_url" name="<?php echo $this->get_field_name('image_uri'); ?>" id="<?php echo $this->get_field_id('image_uri'); ?>" value="<?php echo $instance['image_uri']; ?>" style="margin-top:5px;">

    <input type="button" class="button button-primary custom_media_button" id="custom_media_button" name="<?php echo $this->get_field_name('image_uri'); ?>" value="Upload Image" style="margin-top:5px;" />
</p>

<?php
    }
}
?>
```

The image is displayed on front end and so is//

*Hey there Sailor! My name is.*

But instead of the "name" inserted into the input field the "Left Sidebar" name is displayed instead.

I'm not sure how to fix this.
So my question is, where did I go wrong?
What part of the code can I alter in order for the data from the name input to be displayed correctly instead of the name of the sidebar?
Please Help.

Comment: What specifically is your desired output/functionality?

Comment: @AndrewBartel I am trying to type in a username in the input field and then have it displayed on front end along with the uploaded image.

Answer (score 0):

Okay so it works now.
The data from the name input is now displayed on front end along with the uploaded image.
I honestly can't explain why...
but I basically just copied some lines from the tutorial link I posted and pasted it where it belongs and everything started to work the way it should.

Here is the new* code//

```
// widget class
class eotw_w extends WP_Widget {

function eotw_w() {
    $widget_ops = array('classname' => 'eotw-w');
    $this->WP_Widget('eotw-w-widget', 'Editor of the Week', $widget_ops);
}

function widget($args, $instance) {
    extract($args);
$title = apply_filters('widget_title', $instance['title'] );
    $name = $instance['name'];
     $image_uri = $instance['image_uri'];

    // widget content
    echo $before_widget;
            if ( $title )
        echo $before_title . $title . $after_title;


    if ( $name )
        printf( '<p>' . __('This weeks EOTW is %1$s ', 'example') . '</p>', $name );
?>
    <img class="eotw-edit" src="<?php echo esc_url($instance['image_uri']); ?>" />

<?php
    echo $after_widget;

}

function update($new_instance, $old_instance) {
    $instance = $old_instance;
    $instance['title'] = strip_tags( $new_instance['title'] );
    $instance['name'] = strip_tags( $new_instance['name'] );
    $instance['image_uri'] = strip_tags( $new_instance['image_uri'] );
    return $instance;
}

function form($instance) {  
        //Set up some default widget settings.
    $defaults = array( 'title' => __('Editor of the Week', 'example'), 'name'     => __('Bilal Shaheen', 'example'));
    $instance = wp_parse_args( (array) $instance, $defaults ); ?>

    <p>
        <label for="<?php echo $this->get_field_id( 'title' ); ?>"><?php _e('Title:', 'example'); ?></label>
        <input id="<?php echo $this->get_field_id( 'title' ); ?>" name="<?php echo $this->get_field_name( 'title' ); ?>" value="<?php echo $instance['title']; ?>" style="width:100%;" />
    </p>

<p>
    <label for="<?php echo $this->get_field_id('name'); ?>">name</label><br />
    <input type="text" name="<?php echo $this->get_field_name('name'); ?>" id="<?php echo $this->get_field_id('name'); ?>" value="<?php echo $instance['name']; ?>" class="widefat" />
</p>
<p>
    <label for="<?php echo $this->get_field_id('image_uri'); ?>">Image</label><br />

    <?php
        if ( $instance['image_uri'] != '' ) :
            echo '<img class="custom_media_image" src="' . $instance['image_uri'] . '" style="margin:0;padding:0;max-width:100px;float:left;display:inline-block" /><br />';
        endif;
    ?>

    <input type="text" class="widefat custom_media_url" name="<?php echo $this->get_field_name('image_uri'); ?>" id="<?php echo $this->get_field_id('image_uri'); ?>" value="<?php echo $instance['image_uri']; ?>" style="margin-top:5px;">

    <input type="button" class="button button-primary custom_media_button" id="custom_media_button" name="<?php echo $this->get_field_name('image_uri'); ?>" value="Upload Image" style="margin-top:5px;" />
</p>

<?php
}
}
?>
```