# Help With Custom Image and Text Widget

Tags: images, widgets, links, widget-text

I recently got into making a custom WordPress theme and I've learned a lot along the way, but I've hit a roadblock with making a custom widget.This is the basic output HTML I'd like my widget to output:

```
<div class="work-column">
   <img src="images/hero.jpg" class="ui image">
     <div class="info">
          <p>Rihana <span>Digital</span></p>
     </div>
     <a href="project.html"></a>
</div>
```

So it looks like this:
[image]

I got some of it down I got the basics of the widget form in the back-end, by looking into a quite a few tutorial, but most of them relate text widgets. Basically I have to admit I don't know how to add image upload and a make it so that the image links to something.

This is the widget back-end now:
[image: This is the widget back-end now]

This is the widget output currently:
[image: this is the widget output currently]

Here's the widget code I've been messing around with:

```
<?php

class my_plugin extends WP_Widget
{

    // constructor
    public function my_plugin()
    {
        parent::WP_Widget(false, $name = __('My Image Widget', 'wp_widget_plugin'));

    }

// widget form creation
    public function form($instance)
    {

// Check values
        if ($instance) {
            $textarea = $instance['textarea'];
        } else {
            $textarea = '';
        }
        ?>

<p>
<label for="<?php echo $this->get_field_id('textarea'); ?>"><?php _e('Description:', 'wp_widget_plugin');?></label>
<textarea class="widefat" id="<?php echo $this->get_field_id('textarea'); ?>" name="<?php echo $this->get_field_name('textarea'); ?>" rows="1" cols="1" ><?php echo $textarea; ?></textarea>
</p>

<?php
}

    public function update($new_instance, $old_instance)
    {
        $instance = $old_instance;
        // Fields
        $instance['textarea'] = strip_tags($new_instance['textarea']);
        return $instance;
    }

    // display widget
    public function widget($args, $instance)
    {
        extract($args);

        // these are the widget options
        $textarea = $instance['textarea'];
        echo $before_widget;

        // Display the widget

        // Check if textarea is set
        echo '<div class="info">';
        if ($textarea) {
            echo '<p><span>' . $textarea . '</span></p>';
        }
        echo '</div>';
        echo $after_widget;
    }
}

// register widget
add_action('widgets_init', create_function('', 'return register_widget("my_plugin");'));
?>
```

As a WordPress newbie, I'd be very grateful if someone could give me some pointers, thanks.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Create Image Uploader for Widget](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/127299/create-image-uploader-for-widget)

Comment: I believe the approach of using widgets for this is not a good idea. Widgets don't really scale, the interface isn't very practical for handling a large number. It would seem much better if each "project" in your site is some actual WordPress content – a Post, or a Jetpack Portfolio item. Then you can use the Featured image to upload the image. You can have a look at the code of Argent, to see an example (Portfolio template): https://argentdemo.wordpress.com/portfolio/

Comment: So, you recommend to go with a custom post type?

Comment: Yes, I would use either regular Posts, or a custom Portfolio post type. Depends if you want to use the Posts for something else, such as a blog. A smart option would be to use the Jetpack Portfolio post type, provided by the Jetpack plugin. This has the benefit that your content is compatible with many other themes. If 5 years later you want to switch to a new theme, you can do it easily...